# custom metronome is not consistent

Tags: unity, audio, music, time, deltatime

In Unity 2022.3.12f1, I made a metronome. Here is a minimal working example:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Metronome : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int tempo = 150;
    public int tempoReference = 4; //e.g., 4 means reference is a quarter note, 2 means reference is a double note,...
    public int timeSignatureTop = 4;
    public int timeSignatureBottom = 4;
    public AudioSource source; //You have to fill this with any short sound
    
    private float delayBeforeNextBeat;        
    private float beatDuration = 0;
    private bool play = false;
    private int beatIndex = 0;

    public void Start()
    {
        source.Play();
        beatDuration = 60f / (timeSignatureBottom / tempoReference * tempo);
        delayBeforeNextBeat = beatDuration;
        beatIndex = 0;
        play = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (play)
        {
            delayBeforeNextBeat -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (delayBeforeNextBeat <= 0)
            {
                beatIndex = (beatIndex + 1) % timeSignatureTop;
                delayBeforeNextBeat = beatDuration + delayBeforeNextBeat;
                source.Play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the interval between the first two beats (as heard through the `AudioSource`) is much longer that the next ones. Additional prints indicate that `Time.deltaTime`s are not particularly longer nor more numerous in this interval than they are in others, though.

I tried to move everything in `FixedUpdate`, with the same result.

I also tried to move the first `source.Play()` inside the `Update` function (with some minor adjustments, like adding a `bool firstPlay` and initializing `beatIndex` to -1), with the same result.

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: Have you looked into [PlayScheduled](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayScheduled.html)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. No I didn't, but I'm not sure it is relevant to my problem, as my metronome (more complex than the minimal example) is used to synchronise together other sound events to a unified tempo. But maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's what it's for.

Comment: I see. Many thanks, I will look into that.

Comment: After checking the function, that is definitely something I will use, thanks again!

As a matter of fact, the documentation of PlayScheduled also indirectly answers to my question. I.e., an audio event has to be planned in advance. A comment in the code example explains: "We are now approx. 1 second before the time at which the sound should play, so we will schedule it now in order for the system to have enough time to prepare the playback at the specified time. This may involve opening buffering a streamed file and should therefore take any worst-case delay into account."